# How can I sort a list of numerical strings? Preferably using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I have a string in below manner:-

```
string[] things = new string[] { "1", "10", "2", "1_1", "2_1","3_1" };
```

The desired output is:

```
"1",
"1_1",
"2",
"2_1",
"3_1",
"10",
```

How I can achieve this using LINQ?

Comment: Do you always have that format with '_'? Or do you have any other characters? Could you maybe explain in what context you need this?

Comment: Those aren't special characters. They are just characters. You have a list of *strings*, not numbers, which means they are sorted alphabetically. Why should `"10"` come last? What kind of sorting do you want? What are the rules?

Comment: [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) allows you to specify any value as a key, not only the original value. You can parse the strings and return a double/decimal key

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. If you would post at least own attempt of your own to show how you tried to solve that problem, it would drastically increase the quality of your question. Also that is what the people expect here to see ;) at least a little effort on your own :) Good fortune

Comment: sorting rule is : first number, then if underscore that is priority and after special character sorting based on numbers. underscore describes that the string is a sub part. Means "1_1" is a sub part of 1

Comment: @Digambar update the question with the rule. The question doesn't make any sense otherwise. Besides, how is this different than treating `_` as a decimal separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that format is strict you could parse to [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) and order by that:

```
string[] orderedThings = things
   .Select(t => new { Thing = t, Numbers = (t + "_0").Split('_') })
   .Where(x => x.Numbers.All(s => s.All(char.IsDigit)))
   .Select(x => new { x.Thing, VersionStr = String.Join(".",x.Numbers.Take(4)) })
   .OrderBy(x => new Version(x.VersionStr))
   .ThenBy(x => x.Thing)
   .Select(x => x.Thing)
   .ToArray();
```

The `t + "_0"` trick was necessary to ensure that also single digits can be parsed. A version needs at least a major and aminor part. This "works" also if there are more than 4 tokens(major, minor, build, and revision). Then only the first 4 are taken to initialize the `Version` instance.

Comment: Considering the flexibility it is giving for multiple number of '_' this is the best option.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, you can split each part by `_` and convert the first string part to an integer. When sorting afterwards this will ensure that `10` is not before `2`. Then in the second step you order it according to the last number

```
string[] things = new string[] { "5_3", "5_2", "1", "10", "2", "1_1", "2_1", "1_2", "3_1" };

string[] ordered = things.OrderBy(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('_').First())).                       
                           ThenBy(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('_').Last())).ToArray();
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT: Here is the link to the [documentation of ThenBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx) for the sake of informativity ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
string[] strings = new string[] { "1", "10", "2", "1_1", "2_1", "3_1" };

var ordered = from str in strings
                let weight = double.Parse(str.Replace("_", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator))
                let pair = new { Weight = weight, OriginalString = str }
                orderby pair.Weight
                select pair.OriginalString;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the desired output:

```
string[] things = new string[] { "1", "10", "2", "1_1", "2_1", "3_1" };
var list =  from row in things select Decimal.Parse(row.Replace("_",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator));
list = list.OrderBy(d=> d).ToList();
var StringList = from row in list select row.ToString("0.#").Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, "_");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the overloads of [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that allows you to create your own key and maybe specify your own comparer. It looks like you want to treat `_` as a decimal separator.

One quick & dirty way would be to replace `_` with the decimal separator, eg :

```
var decSeparator=CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

var orderedThings=things.OrderBy(thing=>double.Parse( thing.Replace("_",decSeparator)) )
                        .ToArray();
```

This is quick & dirty because it assumes `_` appears only once. If `_` appeared multiple times, the replaced string wouldn't be a valid number